# No module named 'tensorflow.keras.model'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Whenever I try to train my module it shows the following error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.model'

```
import numpy as numpy
import cv2
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.model import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Maxpooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: It is `models` not `model`. Change it to `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential), your imports are incorrect. `Sequential` is stored in `tensorflow.keras`. I also ran into a problem importing `Maxpooling2D` which is actually called `MaxPool2D` (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MaxPool2D)).

Your imports should therefore be:

```py
import numpy as numpy
import cv2
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import MaxPool2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```